# Write XMP data in image EXIF programmatically

Tags: android, flutter, exif, xmp

I am trying to write custom EXIF data in my images from my Android app, but i see that there are tags non existing from the `ExifInterface` that appear on some images such as `Yaw`, `Pitch` `Roll` and an `XMP` toolkit.

I could not find any Android / Flutter package to write these tags and my client ask me to write the XMP data somewhere and print in inside the EXIF of the image.

I have asked about it in this [repo](https://github.com/adobe/XMP-Toolkit-SDK/issues/68) but got no answer yet.

I would like to know exactly what is XMP and how to write values into a "XMP" file programmatically (Java / dart).
Is it a server side thing or can it be done client side ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

Please click this link to know more about XMP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform

This as well: https://neededapps.com/tutorials/what-are-image-metadata-exif-iptc-xmp/

In a nutshell, XMP stores information about the changes made to your image in post-processing.

Now, as for writing XMP data, here is the library you'll need: https://github.com/dragon66/pixymeta-android

And here is a sample GitHub question that shows how to edit XMP data: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues/277

I'm not too fluent in Dart so I only provided Java code. Sorry for that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually this is already very helpful even in Java, let my try this later before accepting your answer but it seems at a very first sight to answer my needs.

Comment: Hi there, Did it work?

Comment: I am really sorry i have still no time to check it out currently, be sure i will update here once done. Thanks